# How to append render layers from one scene to another?

Tags: rendering, render-layers, append

I have two scene versions. The scene content of both are equal, but I have added some new render layers to the second version.

Now I would like to append the render layers from version 2 -> version 1.

Is this possible without append the objects?

The plugin [Copy Render Layer Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Copy_Render_Layer) is unfortunately not working with version 2.79, that I am using currently.

Thank you
Chris